# How to treat ASCII code as a string rather than it's character

Tags: c#, escaping, ascii

When checking a string that contains an ASCII code e.g. `ABC\x30XYZ`, how can I read it as exactly that full string, rather than reading it as the string `ABC0XYZ`?

For example:

```
var value = "ABC\x30XYZ";
foreach(var c in value)
{
    Console.Write(c);
} 
// Desired output: ABC\x30XYZ
// Actual output: ABC0XYZ
```

I'm guessing I need to do something with Encoding but I'm struggling to find the solution. I feel like I'm missing something really obvious and am prepared to hang my head in shame when someone points this out.

Comment: That's just the way you type it in C# as a literal because of escaping, the actual binary representation contains a single Unicode code point. For example, you could do other characters as well `"\x41"` is exactly the same as `"A"`

Comment: So in my example above, would the substring `\x30` not actually exist at runtime, regardless of using some specific encoding etc?

Comment: Correct, it's just how you write a literal. In your case `\x30` is just `0`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you create the string yourself, you need to escape "\x30" ASCII notation for it to be treated as a string:

```
var value = "ABC\\x30XYZ";
```

If you want to parse ASCII codes out of an input string, you could use regex parsing like:

```
 var value = "ABC\\x30XYZ";
 var values = Regex.Matches(value, @"\\x[\d]{2}|.");
 foreach (var c in values)
 {
    Console.Write(c);
 }
```

Use an appropriate regex based on the input format you expect.

Comment: Thank you. This was the head-shaking moment I was prepared for... As an alternative to what you mentioned, I could also just declare the string using the verbatim identifier `@`.